# There is to such thing

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, prepositional-phrases, grammaticality-in-context

> “Talk of inspiration is sheer nonsense; **there is to such thing**. It is mere a matter of craftsmanship.”
>
> — William Morris

I don't understand the quote, particularly the part I highlighted. I am confused about the preposition *to* as well as the expression *to such thing*.

I assumed that *to such thing* could mean *to the extent of/that*,

> Talk of inspiration is sheer nonsense *to the extent that we shouldn't even talk about it*.
>
> *It's absolute nonsense, let's not talk about it.*

but *sheer* has already covered that meaning, so we don't need *"to the extent"* part:

> Talk of inspiration is *sheer* (=complete) nonsense <strike>*to the extent that ...*</strike>.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: it's a typo, which seems to have managed to propagate across the interwebz by bloody-minded copy/paste. "there is **no** such thing."

Comment: @Tetsujin really? there are tons of high-quality images (like 3k x 2k) with that quote, how on earth can someone be so careless?

Comment: To paraphrase... a typo can be halfway round the world before the original quote has it's boots on ;) It's the *modern way*, find something & re-post it to farcebork or twatter before even considering what it actually means or whether it's accurate...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the phrase in question is a typographical error.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I am gonna remove it now, thank you, guys. (I couldn't)

Comment: I think we ought to leave it here as a reference for all the people who keep copy/pasting the wrong quote... & as a help for non-natives who don't realise the quote has been mangled.

Comment: Also, as a warning to anyone who ever relies on the internet to source a quote. Just to be clear: the internet is stunningly unreliable on quotes, particularly with respect to attributions. Unless you have a complete work, assume the quote and attribution are wrong until verified by a reliable source.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The original quote has been so badly mangled by someone who simply failed to copy it out correctly in the first place.

It has then been handed round the internet by others who simply never bothered to check if it was correct.. or even if it made any sense at all.

Maybe they thought [William Morris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Morris) lived some time before Shakespeare & so "spoke funny", or maybe they just didn't think at all.

"to such thing" & "mere a" are simply garbage; not English.

The correct original quote is...

> That talk of inspiration is sheer nonsense; there is no such thing. It is a mere matter of craftsmanship.

& here's a picture from an [old actual real book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=b084AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA2&lpg=PA2&dq=Talk%20of%20inspiration%20is%20sheer%20nonsense&source=bl&ots=H3nxUX7ClQ&sig=M8xWd5NbUX664lWDfychJPWIYek&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiT_KaBp-LcAhUkI8AKHeG_Aj4Q6AEwCnoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=Talk%20of%20inspiration%20is%20sheer%20nonsense&f=false), from before the interwebz was invented

[image]

In fact if you search [Google for Books](https://www.google.co.uk/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=Talk%20of%20inspiration%20is%20sheer%20nonsense) rather than everything, all the references agree.

To paraphrase the original [correct] quote...

> Inspiration does not exist. All that exists is craftsmanship.

Comment: "mere a" also triggered me, but "to such thing" made me forget about it.

Answer (score 6):

As @Tetsujin suggests, it's a Typo.

You can find the original Quote on [Google Books](https://books.google.de/books?id=2Jz0af5mXA8C&pg=PA186&dq=%E2%80%9CTalk%20of%20inspiration%20is%20sheer%20nonsense%22William%20Morris&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvnca4n-LcAhUJzaQKHQPKCykQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%9CTalk%20of%20inspiration%20is%20sheer%20nonsense%22William%20Morris&f=false), where it reads

> "That talk of inspiration is sheer nonsense, [..] there is **n**o such thing"

(emphasis by me)

It has wrongly been quoted on [quotefancy](https://quotefancy.com/quote/1334538/William-Morris-Talk-of-inspiration-is-sheer-nonsense-there-is-to-such-thing-It-is-mere-a) and [azquotes](https://www.azquotes.com/quote/1311258) and other pages.